# jQuery Mobile CSS is changing my navbar CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am making a website search bar using jQuery Mobile. But, the jQuery CSS always changes the way the website looks. What should I do?

```js
$('#navbar-search').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $('#navbar-searchbar').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.navbar-default {
 background-color: #7289DA;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default:hover .navbar-brand:hover {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #23272A;
}

.glyphicon-user-hover:hover {
  color: #23272A;
}

/* Bounce To Bottom */
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom:hover, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}

/* Bounce To Right */
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098D1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover, .hvr-bounce-to-right:focus, .hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}

.glyphicon-user{
 color: white;
}

.width-100px {
  width: 100px;
}

.width-174px{
  width: 174px;
}

.margin-top-8px{
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="">
    <title>Lyrics Master</title>

    <!--jQuery Mobile-->
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"-->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://lyricsmaster.ml/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Custom CSS for this page-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Lyrics Master</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown hvr-bounce-to-bottom">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hvr-bounce-to-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-user-hover" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="hvr-bounce-to-right"><a href="">Login</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-bounce-to-right"><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" id="navbar-search">
              <a href="">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <div class="input-group width-174px margin-top-8px hide" id="navbar-searchbar">
              <input type="text" class="form-control width-100px" id="myFilter" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" placeholder="Search">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="navbar-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!--jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins)-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://lyricsmaster.ml/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript-->
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    <!--jQuery For Search-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--jQuery Mobile For Search-->
    <!--script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script-->
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks without jQuery Mobile CSS and Javascript -[Without JQM CSS and JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNwO6.png)

This is what it looks with jQuery Mobile CSS and Javascript -[With JQM CSS and JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdffQ.png)

I have seen all the StalkOverflow Pages on this topic, but, I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Provide proper snippets.

Comment: What are snippets?

Comment: Your above codes ar not compiling becasue you are using chunks of code .. like script in one snippet , html in other,. Make a proper code example.. All will come in one snippet example.. I think you are new here..

Comment: I made an account today. So, I don't know much about Stack Overflow. But, I guess I know what you mean. Do you want me to write the whole code in the boxes provided by Stack Overflow? (In which the top left box is for HTML, then, CSS and JavaScript)

Comment: Yes.. that will be a working example then.. because I know the solution to your question.

Comment: Can I do that tomorrow? Because I am on an Android device now and there is no option on this website to edit snippets using mobile.

Comment: Cool No problems.. just tag me in your comment when you are done on that.,

Comment: I have edited it :)

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a touch-optimized web __framework__ for smartphones and tablets. It provides a unified user interface system across all popular mobile device platforms, built on jQuery.

Comment: ok I 'll just check and tell you